# concatenate key object with same values or create new object if value is different

Tags: typescript

I have a structure like this :

```
const carArray = [{
  "brand": "Mercedes",
  "revision": [
     {"1980": {"has_been_done": "true"}},
     {"1985": {"has_been_done": "true"}},
     {"1990": {"has_been_done": "false"}}, 
     {"1995": {"has_been_done": "true"}},
     {"2000": {"has_been_done": "false"}}
  ]
}]
```

I want to get this kind of result:

```
{
  [
    {"1980, 1985, 1995": {"has_been_done": "true"}},
    {"1990, 2000": {"has_been_done": "false"}}      
  ]
}
```

I tried something like that, and of course it can't work because I stay focus on the first element of array instead of checking the content of each lines indifferently:

```
const finalArray: {}[] = [];
let firstYear: string;
let index = 0;

this.carArray[0].revision.forEach( rev => {
    for (const [year, revisionValue] of Object.entries(rev)) {
      // Push the first element 
      if (index === 0) {
        firstYear = year;
        finalArray.push({[year]: revisionValue});
      } else {
        // Check if the current revision value is equal to what's inside the array
        if (JSON.stringify(revisionValue) === JSON.stringify(finalArray[0][firstYear])) {
          // Concat the years 
          finalArray[0] = ({[firstYear.concat(',', year)]: revisionValue});
          firstYear = firstYear.concat(',', year);
        } else  {
          // Add a new line if values are not already inside the array
          finalArray.push({[year]: revisionValue});
        }
      }        
      index ++;
    }
  }
);
```

The thing is, I don't know how to compare the values whatever the index, the comparison with only the first array element only is a problem but I don't know how to make without it.

Does someone has an idea ?

Comment: your desired output isn't valid json

Comment: It doesn't make too much sense to set a complex dynamically created string as key of an object. You might just want to put it side by side as a value with `has_been_done`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first sort the keys, then put them inside an object

```
const hasBeenDone: string[] = []
const hasntBeenDone: string[] = []

this.carArray[0].revision.forEach(revision => {
  Object.keys(revision).forEach(year => {
    if(revision[year].has_been_done) hasBeenDone.push(year)
    else hasntBeenDone.push(year)
  })
})

const result = {
  [
    {[hasBeenDone.join(', ')]: {has_been_done: true}},
    {[hasntBeenDone.join(', ')]: {has_been_done: false}},
  ]
}
```

Or a bit prettier

```
const result = this.carArray.map(car => {
  const {hasBeenDone, hasntBeenDone} = car.revision.reduce(
    ({hasBeenDone, hasntBeenDone}, revision) => {
      Object.keys(revision).forEach(year => {
        if(revision[year].has_been_done) hasBeenDone.push(year)
        else hasntBeenDone.push(year)
      })
      return {hasBeenDone, hasntBeenDone}
    },
    {hasBeenDone: [] as string[], hasntBeenDone: [] as string[]}
  )
  return [
    {[hasBeenDone.join(', ')]: {has_been_done: true}},
    {[hasBeenDone.join(', ')]: {has_been_done: true}},
  ]
})
```